# comparing a dictionary containing lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists which contains 26 keys, each of which has 26 list of a given length. These keys represent the letters of the English Latin alphabet. The list contain occurrences of a given character in a given spot for words of a certain length. For example if we want to represent the occurrence of words of length 5, I may receive the following output:

> D = {'a': [5, 2, 0, 1, 4], …., 'z': [0, 7, 5, 2, 1]}

My goal is to compare key a to key z by index. So I want to compare 'a':[5] to 'z':[0] and if 'a' > 'z' then I want to return a. Essential I want to compare each index and if that index is larger, I want to return the letter for that index. My current code is as follows:

```
def most_common_character_by_index(D):

    for key in D:
        for value in key:
            f = map(D[key], D[value] )
    print(list[f])
```

The thought was to map the indices and compare each. Perhaps I'm missing something? The current error code returns:  print(list[f])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Maybe an example will help explain what you're trying to say

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what you want to do. Can you give a small example, it doesn't hace to be 26 keys, and the lists can be small, but it isn't at all clear to me what you are trying to do... what does "'a':[5] to 'z':[0]" mean?

Comment: Provide a [mcve], example input and example output.

Comment: @Pitto there *is* an attempt, but it's still not very clear

Comment: Switching your square brackets to parens in your last line will fix your current error.  Working from there might help give a clearer example of what you're trying to accomplish.
    print(list(f))

Comment: So if I have two keys in D, such that 'a': 3,4, 5, and 'z': 1,2,6 in the for D = {'a': 3,4,5, 'z': 1, 2, 6}. Then I want to create a max function such that the max at index zero returns a. Then the max at index 2 will return 'z'. I want to compare the list inside of each of the keys, and whichever index is larger, I want to return the key. I hope this makes sense. I know this is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Example: D = {'a': [3,4,5], 'z': [1,2,6]}, max function: for keys in D: if current-index >  previous-index: return larger key, else: return current key. So ['a'][0] > ['z'][0] and, ['a'][2] < ['z'][2]. For the 0th index, I want to return a. For the 2nd index I want to return z.

Comment: Please inform where I can improve my explanation. Perhaps I've done a poor job explaining. I just want to compare the indices of lists contained in the keys. So I want to compare a[0] to z[0], but not a[0] to z[1] or z[2]. I want to find out what is the largest 0th index, then 1st index, and so on.

Comment: @Dale, so you want generate (hypotetically) the most likely word for a given wird length?

Comment: @000 , no I want to return the most common occurring characters for a word of a given length. If we have a common length of 3, and a, z, and j are the most common occurring characters respectively, then I would like to return a, then z, then j. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Dale, that's what I meant. You are chosing the most common letter for every position, composing in that way the most likely word. Then, this word might be meaningless, _ca va sans dire_... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def mostCommonLetters(D):

    numberOfValues = len(D['a'])

    listOfMostCommonLetters = []

    for i in range(numberOfValues):
        currMax = D['a'][i]
        mostCommonLetter = 'a'
        for letter in D:
            if D[letter][i] >= currMax:
                currMax = D[letter][i]
                mostCommonLetter = letter
        listOfMostCommonLetters.append(mostCommonLetter)

    return listOfMostCommonLetters

print(mostCommonLetters({'a': [5, 2, 0, 1, 4],'z': [0, 7, 5, 2, 1]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is this:

```
list[f]
```

you are putting brackets which means you are trying to subscritp the `list` constructor. Hence the error.

What you want is

```
list(f)
```

Anyway, there are other problems:

`for value in key:` will iterate over the key itself, you may want `for value in D[key]`.

Also, `f` is used out of the loop.